# Geting values from files with different types and putting them into arraylist

Tags: java, output

I wonder how to use values from txt file to put them into array list using different types and put them into separate number class.
For example txt file format
`TV  2001  Samsung  white  new
TV  2002  Samsung  black  new`

I have Main class

```
public class Item {
    private String Type;
    private int year;
    private String mfg;
    private String condition;
    private String color;
}
```

With Constructor

```
public Item (String t, int y, String m, String con, String c) {
    Type = t;
    year = y;
    mfg = m;
    condition = con;
    color = c;
}
```

And there is a txt file with following (note there is more that one line)

`TV  2001  Samsung  white  new`

How to get those value to put in the item constructor? and each item has a different number for example first line Item i1 = new Item(); line 2 has i2 etc...
I know only how to get entire line and String tipe

I do have set and get constructors thanks ahead

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourfilename));
String dataRow=null; 
while ( (dataRow= br.readLine()) dataRow != null){
    try{
        String[] temp = dataRow.trim().split("\\s+");
        Item itm = new Item(temp[0], Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), temp[2], temp[3], temp[4]);
        itemList.add(itm);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Assuming the `.txt` file format is fixed as below

```
TV  2001  Samsung  white  new
TV  2002  Samsung  black  new
....
```